# Recycler View - disable Drag and Drop or Swipe actions for just few selected row from a list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I want to create a list, for example, To-Do List. 
In this User is allowed to select/unselect an item, reorder according to their priority. In the current scenario, I am able to give them all of the above functionality using **`ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`**. 
My Challenge starts here -

- When User selects an item(or right swipe it) I need to show that row disabled with strike-through text.
- In such a case, I am changing its position and after that, all features like **`Drag & Drop`**, **`Swipe Left or Right`** should **not work** on that particular row.
- And, If the user manually **unselects** it by tapping an icon, all the mentioned **gestures should work.**

I read about Method **`getSwipeDirs`** but didn't understand how to utilize it in my scenario.

I have gone through a couple of articles but all of them remove an item on swipe. Hence, I couldn't find the reference for my case.

If anyone has an idea about it and guide me further then it would be a great help! I am open

***Note:*** I have used **com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout** library just for left swipe as I want to enable full swipe just for Right direction. I am able to disable the library swipe by utilizing some of its methods. However, I still can not disable **Drag/Drop or Right Swipe** which I am using with help of **`ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`**.

Comment: You can try use this way https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/issues/4#issuecomment-120979332

Comment: Thanks. I did it with the provided way! Also, I needed to use view holders Tag to pass data of specific rows to detect it's the current condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply add the tag to the `viewHolder of recyclerView` and fetch the info from the tag for any particular row in the `getMovementFlags method of ItemTouchHelper.Callback` and manipulate drag/ drop or swipe flag as needed!